# proof that a matrix $M$ is positive definite iff all its eigenvalues are strictly positive.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, hermitian-matrices

By definition, an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ is positive definite iff
$$\forall z\in\mathbb R^n:z^TAz>0$$

We want to show that this is satisfied iff for all eigenvalues $\lambda _i $ of $M$, we have
$$\lambda_i >0$$

We can show this by decomposing $M$ into a diagonal matrix: $$M=P^{-1}DP$$
where $P$ is the matrix built up by the eigenvectors of $M$, and where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the main diagonal.

Then if we dfine $y=Pz$, we can rewrite the criterion as:

$$z^TP^{-1}Dy>0$$

However, in the text I found on wikipedia, they go one step further, and rewrite it as 
$$\forall y\in \mathbb R^n: y^TDy>0$$
**From that condition it is easy to see that all eigenvalues must be strictly positive, but I don't know how this conclusion is reached since $y^T=z^TP^T\neq z^TP^{-1}$**

ps. here is the source:

[image]

---

**Edit:** I now understand that $z^TP^T=z^TP^{-1}$ is based on the assumption that $M$ is symmetric and therefore $P$ is orthogonal. **However, I am wondering, can we still say that a *non-symmetric* $M$ is positive definite *iff* all its eigenvalues are strictly positive?**

Comment: You can choose the eigenvectors to form an orthonormal basis. Then your matrix $P$ is unitary (or orthogonal), meaning that $P^{-1} = P^T$.

Comment: You should assume that $M$ is symmetric

Comment: @egreg OP did that already by decomposing it.

Comment: @amsmath If $M$ is not symmetric, it's not necessarily diagonalizable.

Comment: @egreg Right. And therefore not decomposable. But OP uses the decomposition. Therefore, they must have assumed $M$ to be symmetric.

Comment: @amsmath, Actually, I assumed that as long as $A$ is a full rank matrix, it is diagonalizable. Apparently I'm wrong. Also, why is it necessarily possible for the eigenvectors to form an orthonormal basis? Wouldn't this completely depend on the eigenvectors? i.e. wouldn't it almost-always be impossible for them to be orthonormal ? In fact I would guess that they would have to be orthogonal by pure coincidence (then you can make them orthonormal by scaling).

Comment: @Programmer2134 The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$  has rank two and is not diagonalizable. It's quite a deep result that a symmetric matrix can be diagonalized with an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: @Programmer2134 Eigenvectors for different eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal to each other. Hence, if $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_m$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then$$\mathbb R^n = ker\,(A - \lambda_1 I)\oplus\ldots\oplus ker\,(A - \lambda_mI).$$Now, for each eigenspace $ker\,(A-\lambda_jI)$ choose an orthonormal basis. The union of these orthonormal bases will then be an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: The source does start with "Let $M$ be an $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix."

Comment: @DanielSchepler, Right. Does this mean that only symmetric matrices can be positive definite? because I have no idea why that would be the case.

Comment: @egreg, I thought about it some more. Is it true that a matrix can be diagonalized iff its eigenvectors are linearly independent?

Comment: @Programmer2134 An $n\times n$ matrix is diagonalizable if and only if it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: @egreg, That is the same as what I said, isn't it?

Comment: @Programmer2134 Well, not really. The idea is good, but the statement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your source talks about matrices over the complex numbers and $M$ is supposed to be Hermitian, that is, equal to its “conjugate transpose”.

I'll denote by $M^*$ the conjugate transpose of the (generic) matrix $M$. A couple of definitions; let $M$ be a square matrix:

- $M$ is *Hermitian* when $M=M^*$
- $M$ is *normal* when $MM^*=M^*M$

The source also talks about the *spectral theorem*, which says that every *normal matrix* $M$ can be written as
$$
M=\sum_{k=1}^r \lambda_k P_k\tag{*}
$$
where $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $M$ and $P_1,\dots,P_r$ are the projections matrices to the eigenspaces; in particular they satisfy $P_k^2=P_k$ and $P_k^*=P_k$. Moreover $P_kP_l$ is the null matrix when $k\ne l$.

Clearly any Hermitian matrix is normal and it's easy to deduce that if $M$ is Hermitian then its eigenvalues are real: indeed, using its spectral decomposition (*), we have, from $M=M^*$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^r \lambda_kP_k=\sum_{k=1}^r \lambda_k^*P_k
$$
and upon multiplying this by $P_l$ we get $\lambda_l=\lambda_l^*$.

The statement that any Hermitian matrix has real eigenvalues can be proved also without the spectral theorem, by directly using the definition: let $v$ be an eigenvector relative to the eigenvalue $\lambda$; then
$$
\lambda(v^*v)=v^*(\lambda v)=v^*Av=v^*A^*v=(Av)^*v=(\lambda v)^*v=\lambda^*v^*v
$$
Since $v^*v\ne0$, we get $\lambda=\lambda^*$.

Another important fact about normal matrices is that they can be diagonalized with a unitary matrix; this is actually an equivalent condition.

> A square matrix $M$ is normal if and only if there exists a unitary matrix $U$ (that is, $U^{-1}=U^*$) such that $D=U^{-1}MU$ is diagonal.

Now, suppose $M$ is (Hermitian) and positive definite, that is, for $v\ne0$, $v^*Mv>0$. Consider $e_k$, the $k$-th vector of the canonical basis and consider $v_k=Ue_k$; then
$$
0<v_k^*Mv_k=e_k^*U^*UDU^*Ue_k=e_k^*De_k
$$
and, clearly, $e_k^*De_k$ is the entry at place $(k,k)$ in $D$. Since $D$ has on its diagonal the eigenvalues of $M$, we are done.

Conversely, if $D$ has all its diagonal entries positive, then, for every $v\ne0$ we have
$$
v^*Mv=(Uv)^*D(Uv)>0
$$
because clearly $D$ is positive definite.